# My Root disk space is full after an upgrade to the newest version of Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

After I made an upgrade of my Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.04, my root disk space is almost full. I think maybe I have to delete some files that are no longer useful on the new one to free space. If so, how can I do that?
And I notice also my system has become slow. I think it is because of lack of space on root disk.
I want to know if it is possible to resize the root disk without damage. If yes, how can we do that?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 18 or 20. Might you mean Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04?

Comment: @David, I mean 20.04

Comment: As currently written, the question is vague. It lacks information (like output of `df -h`) needed for a useful answer. We don't know if your root partition is too small, or if you have been downloading enormous files (like movies), or other common mistakes that new users make. Therefore, we cannot give you useful advice beyond "figure out why your disk is full." Tools like `du` and `baobab` will happily tell you, if used properly, what the largest space using applications and files are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to resize the root partition on the fly using the GNOME Disks tool. Just keep in mind that in the case your UUID of the partition changes, you need to modify `/etc/fstab` and your GRUB boot parameters accordingly.

By the way, if it is full due to the upgrade packages, you should be able to free some space using `sudo apt clean`. You can also free more space by removing old kernel versions and old snap packages (details on my website here: https://wyphan.github.io/logfile/2020/12/17/kernel-snap-cleanup.html )

Answer (score 0):

Before resizing your root partition I would try two things:

1. **clean the cache**
   apt keeps all downloaded package files in a cache, to delete them , there are two options:

- `sudo apt autoclean` this deletes the packages from cache that can not be downloaded anymore
- `sudo apt clean` this deletes all the packages from cache

2. **uninstall no longer needed packages**
   `sudo apt autoremove`- this will uninstall packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no longer needed.

after that there should be some free space again